# Xcode links a Third Party framework in my Framework and includes it's symbols

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I am building a Framework and the code there uses a Third party framework. When I compile my Framework it seems to contain all the symbols from the Third party framework. If I don't add the third party framework to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` I get compiler errors about undefined symbols.

On the other hand, when I add the third party framework to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` it compiles fine. However, in a sample app when I link both my framework and the third party one I get the following runtime warnings: `Class is implemented in both, One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined`.

My question is how do I build my framework with a dependency on another framework without actually linking it? I want to do all the linking on the app level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn’t able to achieve this behavior building dynamic frameworks. However, as I built my framework as static, the framework compiled fine and did not include third party framework symbols. All the linking with the third party framework has to be done on the app level.

I have seen many questions on stack overflow like this with no definite answer. I hope my finding would help.